# Analytical Solution of the Sod Problem with Different Gammas?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, shock-waves

Is there a known analytical solution to the Sod Shock Tube problem where the two gases have different specific heat ratios $\gamma$? I have only been able to find solutions where the $\gamma$ values are equal in the two gases, as in this Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sod_shock_tube.

Comment: Is $\gamma$ constant in each gas but different between them? And are you assuming anything about where the gas discontinuity is located relative to the pressure/density discontinuity?

Comment: And I guess the other question is how are you defining "analytical" solutions... the traditional case of single gas, constant gamma still requires an iterative solver so that isn't "analytical" either. Are you just looking for an *algebraic* system (instead of a differential or integral equation system)?

Comment: I am looking for a system of algebraic equations to describe the post-shock conditions of the two gases where gas 1 has constant $\gamma_1$ and gas 2 has constant $\gamma_2$. I'm really interested in determining the pressure in an algebraic form at region III in the Wikipedia article from the initial conditions.